# How to create a service in GWT project?

Tags: google-app-engine

Hi I am new to App Engine and a beginner in web services world.
I want to create a service with GET method in my GWT project and I
want to call that service from my JavaScript. I am using Eclipse IDE with GWT
plugin. I have started with that greeting services pages. But how to create a REST
model web service there?

Comment: The point of GWT is that you don't have to hand code JavaScript. If you'd like to do that manually, say with jQuery, you don't need to use GWT. Also you've a google app engine tag which is not mentioned in the question. GWT works well on app engine, but are two different technologies, maybe you want to clarify. Further, even if it was clear, your question is too broad. Google for some tutorials first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Michael & Stivlo.
I understand that GWT is a toolkit that helps me to code in java, compiles it and the result(.war) I can deploy in Google App Engine.
Now I found "Restlet" to be useful for creating Rest services and I am on it.